# Focus box working but i have others texts forms

Tags: javascript, html

I created a [new french website](http://%20www.nightdrink.fr). I had to make a focus box so that my Google Maps search box works on Google Chrome.

Code used

```
setInterval(function(){
    var focusbox;
    focusbox = document.getElementById("pac-input");
    focusbox.focus();
});
```

My trouble is now i have other texts fields after on the webpage, and now they can't be filled and all redirects automatically to the google maps searchbox. Is there anyway to dissociate this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I had to make a focus box so that my Google Maps search box works on Google Chrome."?

Comment: That doesn't sound related to this code.

Answer (score -1):

Well, try to use **setTimeout()** method there and pass a number of milliseconds. Anyways it might not be the perfect solution here, but at least you won't end up with the loop of function calls.